# All FTP programs crash when trying to see local files, including Filezilla, CoreFTP and WinFTP

Tags: windows, ftp, crash, filezilla

I cannot get any FTP programs to be able to see my local files or stop them from crashing when I move around the local file directory. I've tried using Filezilla, CoreFTP and WinFTP as well as Internet Explorer. All of them stop responding and crash when I access any folder in my Documents folder, whether or not they're run as administrator, whether or not I disable Windows Defender real time support (except for IE which seems to forget about the request after I select "Allow" for the program to alter my hard drive).

Sometimes they also crash while trying to access files on the server (I have the cheapest hosting option with Siteground and I'm trying to upload a website I've built).

It does not seem like others have this problem, and I am unsure if my firewall is to blame and if so how to configure it to safely allow for the program to access my local files.

I've checked that I can access the files on the server while using Chrome as an FTP just fine, and I've checked for errors/warnings for the server, the only warning being that my address did not resolve to an IPv6 address (despite working).

I've followed many tutorials to see if I was doing something wrong, but even when I follow them exactly the programs still crash leading me to think the firewall is the likely culprit. I don't have much experience with configuring firewalls and I'm afraid to experiment without guidance.

Thank you for trying to help in advance.

Comment: To test the firewall theory, I would simply disable it temporarily and see how things performed. Once you're done you re-enable it. Assuming you aren't doing much else (e.g. surfing), you should be relatively safe and able to observe program behavior.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found that actually worked was using windows explorer (which doesn't get blocked by a firewall).

I did it by

- opening windows explorer
- clicking on This Computer in the left tab
- selecting at the top: Computer
- then: Add Network Location
- Typing in the ip address or domain name same as you would for any other ftp client

... and then voila! It asks for a password and gives you access to look at, download and upload in a very straightforward manner.